# fullcalendar- event dragging/dropping

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I'm using Fullcalendar. I have only one feature left to be implemented, which is when an existing event is dragged from it's original position to another time or date. I would like to know how I get the dragged object information,not new data (i want old date time(dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt)) which property from the Fullcalendar object do I use? I implemented the drop property;

```
    function eventDropped(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) {
        var id = event.id.toString();
        var start = event.start.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
        var end =  event.end.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
        var date = new Date().format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");   



    var dayDelta=dayDelta ;

    var startday = event.start.format("dd");alert(startday);
    var eventday=startday-dayDelta;//alert(eventday);
    var currentday = new Date().format("dd");//alert(currentday);


    if(eventday<=currentday)
    {
            alert("Cannot move past events.");
            revertFunc();
    }   

    }
```

in this way i could not get the correct result,because i want the full date with time format of draggable event old data